# How to manipulate/modify MQTT msgs?

Tags: mqtt, iot

MQTT is a very well known standard protocol, however there is no standard for the payload structure of the msgs.

I have a MQTT broker works with payload in a format like that: **{"value": "ON"}**
The Device works with payload in a different format like that **{"ON"}**

I need a way to add    the "value:" on the msgs coming from the device.
I need a way to remove the "value:" on the msgs coming from the broker.

How could I manipulate or edit the msgs from the device to make them understandable by the broker?
I would need an "intermediary broker" doing this manipulation I imagine

Which options would you recommend? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard mechanism to do this.

The normal way would be to subscribe to the original messages topic with a client which does the transformation then re-published it on a new topic that the end device is subscribed to.

There are libraries that let you implement your own broker that include hooks that should allow you to manipulate messages on the fly if needed.

Comment: Thanks @hardillb ! Considering the great variety of devices that eventually could talk with each other I was thinking that there were some tools already created to use them :) And yes, indeed, I am looking for something that would be at the end an MQTT Broker, that would receive, inspect and modify the msgs to then send them to another Broker in the expected format. I was thinking that I should not be the only one with this challenge, I'll keep looking for some alternatives :) Thanks for the feedback.
Any other ideas are welcome.